# otherwise redirectTo does not work

Tags: angularjs, routes

trying to set the default route when it fails but for some reason it does not work with my SPA.

here is the current code

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider
   .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'templates/index.html',
      controller: 'IndexCtrl'
   })
   .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
   });
});
```

also tried to change otherwise to

```
.otherwise({
     redirecTo: function(){
         return '/'
     }
 });
```

on the other hand if I put template url within otherwise it works

```
.otherwise({
     templateUrl: 'templates/index.html',
     controller: 'IndexCtrl'
});
```

really don't understand why it behaves differently !?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited one of my ng-Route tests to essentially have the same setup as your `when('/')` and `otherwise` methods, but mine is working just fine:

https://codepen.io/tcraw/pen/vRpOXz

The only thing I can think of at this point is that perhaps your `templateUrl` is incorrect...

Do you have another view to test in the `templates` directory? (e.g. `templates/otherView.html`)

### Reference

- [$routeProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider)